# How do I measure my resting heart rate?

Tags: exercise, cardiology, blood-circulation, heart, heart-rate

I measured my sitting down, relaxed, not moving heart rate, which is around 65-80BPM.

If I do the same measurement laying down, it's anywhere from 50-65BPM. While asleep, it dips into the 40s.

The question I have:

**Which measurement should be taken as 'resting'?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resting heart rate is measured sitting down after having rested for at least 10 minutes and for accuracy, not under the influence of any stimulants (like caffeine).

The normal range in general is between 60-100bpm however, there appears to be some differentiation of ranges between men and women.

Source: [Operational definition of normal sinus heart rate](https://doi.org/10.1016/0002-9149(92)90947-w)